# Why does all email for my POP3 account go to spam?

Tags: gmail, email, gmx

I added a gmx POP3 account, and for some reason, all email that goes to gmail from there (through POP3) ends up with the following message:

[image]

This after I added lots of filters to avoid my email to go to spam from that POP3 account.

I am not sure why Gmail insists on all of these emails being suspected as spam. How can I make Gmail skip the spam classification according to the rules I defined, *and* not include this message for every email I open and this rule was applied on?

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes, internal emails (from the same domain) are not verified with SPF as they do not leave the server and are distributed internally. For this reason, Gmail may mark them as spam (SPF fail), but they are valid emails. You should go to the three dots in the message and click on "Show Original". This will display the message headers and give a clue as to why the messages were marked as spam.